# How to get words in a file which contains a single dot or period?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I want to find table names & column names from a file named 'query' below.

```
var query = "  SELECT accounts.name, SUM((COALESCE((jan_val_c),0)+  ";
query += "  COALESCE((feb_val_c),0)+ COALESCE((march_val_c),0)+ COALESCE((apr_val_c),0)+ ";
query += "  COALESCE((may_val_c),0)+ COALESCE((june_val_c),0)+ COALESCE((july_val_c),0)+   ";
query += "  COALESCE((aug_val_c),0)+ COALESCE((sept_val_c),0)+ COALESCE((oct_val_c),0)+   ";
query += "  COALESCE((nov_val_c),0)+ COALESCE((dec_val_c),0))) AS sales_plan,SUM((COALESCE((jan_actual_val_c),0)+   ";
query += "  COALESCE( (feb_actual_val_c),0)+ COALESCE( (march_actual_val_c),0)+ COALESCE( (apr_actual_val_c),0)+   ";
query += "  COALESCE( (may_actual_val_c),0)+ COALESCE( (june_actual_val_c),0)+ COALESCE( (july_actual_val_c),0)+   ";
query += "  COALESCE( (aug_actual_val_c),0)+ COALESCE( (sept_actual_val_c),0)+ COALESCE( (oct_actual_val_c),0)+   ";
query += "  COALESCE( (nov_actual_val_c),0)+ COALESCE( (dec_actual_val_c),0))) AS Actual_plan ,month_name_c,  ";
query += "   cl_sales_planning_month.year_c, cl_products.volume,cl_brands.name AS brand ,cl_therapies.name   ";
query += "   AS therapy,cl_products.name AS product, accounts.created_by,accounts.assigned_user_id ,   ";
query += "   DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',cl_sales_planning_month.month_name_c,  ";
query += "   cl_sales_planning_month.year_c),'%M-%Y'),'%b-%y' ) AS monthyear FROM cl_sales_planning_month   ";
query += "   LEFT JOIN accounts ON cl_sales_planning_month.account_id_c =accounts.id LEFT JOIN cl_products   ";
query += "   ON cl_sales_planning_month.cl_products_id_c = cl_products.id LEFT JOIN cl_brands ON   ";
query += "   cl_products.cl_brands_id_c=cl_brands.id LEFT JOIN cl_therapies ON   ";
query += "   cl_products.cl_therapies_id_c=cl_therapies.id WHERE   ";
 query += "            cl_sales_planning_month.month_name_c = MONTHNAME(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND  ";
      query += "            cl_sales_planning_month.year_c = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)  AND";

query += "   cl_sales_planning_month.user_id_c IN ("+ params["childs"].value +") ";
query += "   GROUP BY therapy,monthyear   ";
query += "   ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(cl_sales_planning_month.year_c,'%Y') ASC,   ";
query += "  STR_TO_DATE(cl_sales_planning_month.month_name_c,'%M') ASC, Actual_plan DESC   ";
```

For this I have written a Java program:

```
package com.waprau;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SeparateTableNamesColumnNames {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("/home/waprau/Desktop/query");
        //Pattern = new Pattern("([^\\s]+(\\.(?i))$)");

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\s|=|,|\\)|\\(|this.|\\].");

            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                if(scanner.next().matches("(?<!\\.)\\b[a-zA-Z]\\w*\\.[a-zA-Z]\\w*\\b(?!\\.)"))
                 System.out.println(scanner.next());;
               }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With above program I am able to separate all words. But I want to get only those words which contains a single dot or period e.g. accounts.name, cl_sales_planning_month.year_c, cl_products.volume, cl_brands.name, cl_therapies.name etc. However I am not able to find a pattern or whatever which can separate these words from file.

But it is not working.

This is the result I am getting:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match words containing a dot, you can use: `"\\w+\\.\\w+"`?

`\w` matches letters, numbers, and underscores.

However, that would also match something which had more than one period.  You could improve it by using look-arounds to make sure there is not another period before or after the word you are matching:

```
"(?<!\\.)\\b\\w+\\.\\w+\\b(?!\\.)"
```

This matches a word containing a dot, and cannot contain a dot immediately before or after. `\b` is a word boundary.

However, that would match decimal numbers like `123.45`.  Tables can contain numbers, but cannot start with one.  So we could also ensure that each word starts with a letter:

```
"(?<!\\.)\\b[a-zA-Z]\\w*\\.[a-zA-Z]\\w*\\b(?!\\.)"
```

Comment: @waprau, you may need to add double escaping for each backslash, also.  See Joop Eggen's  answer.  Sorry, I know regexes but not Java.

Comment: Please find my question edited with double escaping. But still no success. :-(

Comment: @waprau, please explain what "not working" means. No matches? Wrong matches?  Error message?

Comment: @ dan1111. I have edited my question with result I am getting. Thanks.

Comment: @waprau, the problem is not the regex but your use of the scanner.  Each time you call `scanner.next` it advances to the next item.  So the `scanner.next` that you are printing is always the next one after the regex matches, instead of the one that matched.  Put the result of `scanner.next` into a variable, then use that variable to both check the regex and print the result if it matches.

Comment: Thanks  dan1111. Seems it is working with your last suggestion. Let me try with few more files & I will post here if any issues are there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The period `.` has to be escaped as it means "any character". As this is not normal String escaping (like `\n`) it uses two backslashes: `\\.`

Also `\\s`.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the regex (dan1111's answer appears to cover that). You have a flaw in your Java code, scanner.next() gets the next string, and since you call it twice so you won't print what you matched. Instead you will print the item following every match.

If you change your loop as follows it seems to print what you want:

```
String tmp;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // Store next item so we can match AND print it.
    tmp = scanner.next();
    if (tmp.matches("(?<!\\.)\\b[a-zA-Z]\\w*\\.[a-zA-Z]\\w*\\b(?!\\.)"))
        System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks rvalvik. Seems it is working. Let me try with few more files & I will post if any issues are there. Thanks again.